# Change rotation base of a javafx line

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to rotate a line but instead of rotating from its center it rotates from its left end. I'm creating a clock but with rotatetransition the lines rotate from their center.
Codigo de rotacion:

```
Line contFH = new Line();
contFH.setPrefSize(150, 20);
contFH.setRotate(90);
RotateTransition r1 = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(10),contFH);
r1.setByAngle(360);
r1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
r1.play();
```

I made the following changes and now I get the result I want, but this little problem is generated:

[image]
[image]

the line moves from its axis out of the small circle in the center.
Is there a way to keep it from moving on its axis when rotating?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Analog clock sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637), which rotates the clock hands.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [`Rotate`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) and add it to the line's transformations. Then animate the angle:

```
Line contFH = new Line();

// This doesn't compile, not sure what you're doing here:
// contFH.setPrefSize(150, 20);

//contFH.setRotate(90);
Rotate rotate = new Rotate(90, contFH.getStartX(), contFH.getStartY());
contFH.getTransforms().add(rotate);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 90)),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 450)
);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: The key here is the [constructor arguments](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,double,double)) that provide the pivot point for the rotation around the starting point of the line.

Comment: Thanks James_D problem solved.